# How to find out the PID of a running Windows service from the command line given the service name?

Tags: windows

I have the name of a Windows service as it appears in the service control panel. I know that service is running. How do I get the PID of the service using the windows command line?

(Background: I want to verify if a specific service appears in jconsole or not).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sc queryex <name>
```

See [SC](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb490995.aspx).

Example:

```
>sc queryex Tomcat9

SERVICE_NAME: Tomcat9
    TYPE               : 10  WIN32_OWN_PROCESS
    STATE              : 4  RUNNING
                            (STOPPABLE, NOT_PAUSABLE, ACCEPTS_SHUTDOWN)
    WIN32_EXIT_CODE    : 0  (0x0)
    SERVICE_EXIT_CODE  : 0  (0x0)
    CHECKPOINT         : 0x0
    WAIT_HINT          : 0x0
    PID                : 4908
    FLAGS              :

>
```